# IShellLinkW::GetPath( SLGP_RAWPATH ) does not return the 'raw' target of a lnk file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, lnk

I noticed that the method [IShellLinkW::GetPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw-getpath) returns an empty string if the target of a shortcut points to a special folder, like 'My PC', or a Control Panel applet.

Sample code

```
' CLSID_ShellLink from ShlGuid.h
Dim cShellLink As New CShellLink() 

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Dim persistFile As IPersistFile = DirectCast(cShellLink, IPersistFile) 
persistFile.Load(lnkFilePath, 0)

Dim target As New StringBuilder(260)

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw
Dim lnkW As IShellLinkW = DirectCast(cShellLink, IShellLinkW)
lnkW.GetPath(target, target.Capacity, Nothing, IShellLinkGetPathFlags.RawPath)
```

( Sorry, are too many P/Invokes to share here, but you can find them in [this](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/Easy-Link-File-Viewer/tree/master/src/DevCase/Win32) repository. )

The code above works correctly to retrieve the target of any .lnk file that points to a file or directory. It can't retrieve a target that points to special item / virtual folders.

My questions are:

Is this by design?. If not, what I'm missing or doing wrong? (maybe are my definitions wrong?). And what I have to do in order to retrieve the special target?. Note that I would like to retrieve the target to display it in a `PropertyGrid`, and also to create a new target with a clone of the special target.

Please note that the programming language on which I developed this code does not matter, because I'm firstly asking for orientation, and also I accept any solution written in C#.

Comment: Paths only work for file system objects.  You'd have to get familiar with PIDLs, IShellLinkW::GetIDList() returns them.  Not recommended.

Comment: See [SHGetPathFromIDList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetpathfromidlistw), [SHGetFileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfow) (note that it accepts a `LPCWSTR` but also a `pidl`), [SHGetSpecialFolderLocation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation). The `IShellLinkW` interface also provides a `.Resolve()` method that may come in handy. Use it on the same shell object, then get the `out` address returned by `GetIDList()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but If I call **IShellLinkW.GetIDList**, then **SHGetPathFromIDListW** with the (valid, non-zero) PIDL obtained, I always get an empty string, and the function returns **false** but last win32 error code is zero (**SetLastError** is set to **true**). Why?. I tried various signatures, also the ones from pinvoke.net website.

Comment: Also, I don't get what is the point of using **SHGetFileInfo**, because it seems I only could obtain  the filename (**SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME**) and the file type description (**SHGFI_TYPENAME**). By the way, this function accepts the PIDL that I obtain with **IShellLinkW.GetIDList**, but as I mentioned It seems I can't retrieve the 'raw' lnk target string with this function... just the filename or the file type's description.

Comment: Analyzing these lnk files in a hexadecimal editor, they have a CLSID for the target (eg. **::{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}** which points to My PC), and If I use that CLSID when creating the shortcut calling SetPath (without messing with SetIDList and anything trivial), it works as expected. This discover seems makes the problem easier to solve, because I imagine I can obtain the CLSID from the PIDL. PIDL is a concept I didn't read much at all, so excuse me if I'm saying stupid things. But I will still investigating through the available win32 functions to get the CLSID value...

Comment: After I analyzed the purpose of each documented SH* function, I still don't know how to do this.Also,I'm not sure if the PIDL returned by **IShellLinkW.GetIDList** is an 'absolute' or 'relative' PIDL, which confuses me more,and I don't see a way to determine which of the three types of PIDL it is, appart from calling **SHGetRealIDL** and forget. Also, I tried **SHGetPathFromIDListEx** function but I have the same exact problems as I described when calling **SHGetPathFromIDList**. Damn, I just need to obtain the CLSID written in the lnk file...I don't see how to retrieve this CLSID from a PIDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments box of the main post, in order to retrieve the raw target of a shell link that points to a special, non-file system path (eg. 'My PC'), first we need to retrieve the PIDL by calling `IShellLinkW::GetIDList()`.

Next, we pass that (absolute)PIDL to [SHGetNameFromIDList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shgetnamefromidlist) with the flag [SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_sigdn), and finally this will return a CLSID string that we can specify for the target of a .lnk file with `IShellLinkW::SetPath()`. It works as expected.

Note that I'm not sure if there could exist special scenarios (rare targets of a lnk file) on which this could not work as expected. I didn't found that error case.

And if needed, the normal display name can be obtained with the flag `SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY`, or also by calling the [SHGetFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa) function as mentioned too in the comments box of the main post.

---

Credits for the users that suggested me the PIDL retrieval and its usage, because I was not sure about what to investigate in order to solve this problem.

I also will give credits to [Vanara](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara) open-source library, that helped me to find the right P/Invokes of every SH* function in their source-code, specially [the signature for **SHGetNameFromIDList**](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/b8678e0e3293a62589f7c93255f2f3260dae52b6/PInvoke/Shell32/ShlObj.cs#L5174).

Comment: Many ways to get the DisplayName from a `pidl`, some exposed by the ShellItem interface (`GetDisplayName()`, for example), for bound items - relative or absolute. What you use is related to the context and the type of path. One note about the marshaller: you often see in sample code the use of `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. You should use [Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.alloccotaskmem) (native [CoTaskMemAlloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemalloc)) to free as described.

Comment: If you see someone use [SHGetMalloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetmalloc), to initialize a `IMalloc` Interface, that's old code: that method is superseded by `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

Comment: Thanks for comment and for the tips!. Maybe the next is off-topic but I would like to say that for me **WindowsAPICodePack** seems a much better (consistent) source-code to take as example (and copy) any interface related with IShellItem/IShellFolder/IShellView and etc. Anyways, Vanara has a vast collection of P/Invokes and that is really useful in some cases.